# Javascript Routing Regex Script

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, router

I'm working on a Javascript Router like Backbone, Sammy, Spin. But my requirements are very simple. We should be able to give it a set of routes and their corresponding callbacks and we should be able to process the browsers URL upon request.

How I can replace :id for working with numbers only and :slug for common slugs?

I wrote this code:

```
core.route = function(route, options, callback) {
    var url = options.hash;
    var route_segments = route.split('/').length-1;
    var hash_segments = url.split('/').length-1;
    var route_matcher = new RegExp(route.replace(/:[^\/]+/g, '([\\w-]+)'));
    if (url.match(route_matcher)) {
        if (route_segments === hash_segments){
            callback();
        }
    }
};


core.route('/work/:slug/:id/', options, function() {
    alert("work/example/id");
});

core.route('/work/:id/', options, function() {
    alert("work/id/");
});
```

Comment: It would probably help if you defined what a common slug is.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to define what a slug looks like first. But `\d+` matches strings of numerals in regex, so you could try this:

```
core.route('/work/:slug/(\\d+)/', options, function() {
//...
core.route('/work/(\\d+)/', options, function() {
//...
```

Comment: Works fine thanks! but I need apply to this regex rule: /^(?![0-9]*$)[a-z0-9-]+$/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at Backbone's routing implementation and then you try to just factor out what you really need? That should be possible and you might find [the used regex](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L908) there as well:

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L894

Comment: Thanks, I solved it myself with this code: var route_regex = new RegExp(route.replace(/:[name]+/g, '([\\a-z-]+)').replace(/:[id]+/g, '([\\d]+)'));